# How to pass data from a UIImagePickerController to a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

//I need help in how to pass data from a UIImagePickerController to a UIImageView , this is apart from a larger program i am developing

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import MessageUI

    class ImageSelect: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

func selectedImage(){ //func to choose a Picture from the library

 if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
                let imgSelected = UIImagePickerController()
                imgSelected.delegate = self
                imgSelected.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
                imgSelected.allowsEditing = true
                self.present(imgSelected, animated: true,completion: nil)
```

//Here its my problem*********************************

```
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

 imgSelected1.image = UIImage(imgSelected)// give me a Error <

 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      
    //the imgSelected is a UIImagePickerController
    //the imgSelected1 is a UIImageView

 // how can i get the data from the imgSelected and pass it to the 
 imgSelected1?? 
  //***************************************
      }
 }
}
```

how can I fix this , the error come with : Value of type 'UIImagePickerController' has no member 'image' . I know they are no the same type but I did not knew what else to put

Comment: can you tell what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get image as you need to use imagePickerController's delegate method for pick selected image.

**This method called automatically while you select image**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

   imgSelected1.image  = selectedImage  
}
```

Comment: This really help me , I added some custom coding for my proyect and works like a charm